# What to do about the [hand] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, meta-tags

Yes, there are currently only twenty-two [hand](/questions/tagged/hand) questions on Stack Overflow, so manually updating them is no problem.

My problem is, I'm not exactly sure how to retag some of them, as they fall into a number of categories.

**Hand Gestures**

- [How to construct a language using hand gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664007/how-to-construct-a-language-using-hand-gestures)
- [Detecting open fist and close fist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802688/detecting-open-fist-and-close-fist)

**Fingers**

- [how can I compute number of finger? (openCV + contour Detection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746170/how-can-i-compute-number-of-finger-opencv-contour-detection)
- [Finger tracking / counting using OpenCV convex hull and Convexity Defect functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239651/finger-tracking-counting-using-opencv-convex-hull-and-convexity-defect-functio)

**Poker hands** (these will just get removed, IMHO)

- [Java poker hand evaluator to not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739268/java-poker-hand-evaluator-to-not-working)

**Mouse cursor**

- [Set Pointer (Hand) Cursor Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696225/set-pointer-hand-cursor-objective-c)
- [Mouse cursor change Javascript - linked DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843886/mouse-cursor-change-javascript-linked-div)

The tag says "A pointer style for a mouse.", but that's clearly wrong, since the first use of the [hand](/questions/tagged/hand) tag was for hand gestures.

Maybe I'm overthinking a tag used on 22 questions, but I think the obvious thing to do is remove the [hand](/questions/tagged/hand) tag from all poker and mouse cursor questions; it's a meta tag and is pointless.

What to do about the "hand gesture" and "finger" questions?  Do we need a [hand-gesture](/questions/tagged/hand-gesture) tag for them?  Or is that just as meta and useless?

Comment: Also, can we get some delete votes going on [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783360/physx-3-1-documentation-and-source-code)? Only two to go!

Comment: @Andrew Barber - thanks!

Comment: That tag just seems... dirty, somehow ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hand gesture questions seem to be served well by the [gesture-recognition](/questions/tagged/gesture-recognition) tag. No need for a [hand](/questions/tagged/hand) tag there.

And the finger questions could simply go with a [computer-vision](/questions/tagged/computer-vision) tag. I don't think those need anything more detailed than that either.

So I would simply get rid of the [hand](/questions/tagged/hand) tag on those as well.

Comment: Aha, I knew there had to be some sort of [gesture-recognition] tag, I just couldn't figure out what it was.